# Как обрезать строку до 50 букв в html файле с использованием Django

Tags: html, django

Имеется модель поста

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Так же views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import *
from django.utils import timezone


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {'posts': posts} )
```

В html файле использую

```
{% for post in posts %}
         {{ post.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Выводит полный текст поста, хотелось бы сделать срез до определенного символа , но это делается в самом html файле как я понял. Можете подсказать как? или дать нужную документацию, я почему-то не нашел ничего по этому поводу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Из документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

```
{{ post.text|truncatechars:50 }}
```